# BPC VBA After_Refresh

Tags: vba, excel

I am automating a report that will open an upload template to perform an EVSND and close the upload template in order to complete the report.  When the upload template is closed, I get the message:

> *UploadTemp.xlsm is closed.
>
>   Trimming EvINP function or refresh schedules cannot be completed.*

I understand there are VBA available for After_Refresh, but I do not know how to include this in my code.

This is my code:

```
Dim ULTemplate As Workbook 

Set ULTemplate = Workbooks.Open("C:\UploadTemp.xlsm")

With ULTemplate

Application.Run ("MNU_eSUBMIT_REFSCHEDULE_BOOK_CLEARANDREFRESH")

End With

ULTemplate.Close SaveChanges:=True
```

How would I make Excel wait until the refresh is complete prior to closing this file?

Answer (score 0):

You Could Try this

```
For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count
  ActiveWorkbook.Connections(i).OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = False
  MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Connections(i).OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery
Next    
Activeworkbook.RefreshAll
```

Comment: I tried DoEvents and it didn't work. I am assuming it is because I need to wait on the BPC add-in to finish.

Comment: Try that again please